# Как изменить содержимое переменной. Добавить в текст которой в переменной теги HTML

Tags: php

Есть переменная `$my = "С вас 10 USD";`

Как изменить содержимое этой переменной таким образом чтобы в нее добавить тег HTML? На выходе хочу получить такое `$my = "С вас <b>10 USD</b>";`

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, что именно Вы подразумеваете под *на выходе*

Answer (score 1):

**Версия 1** - если под *на выходе* Вы подразумеваете выход в html.

Используйте функцию [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$my = "С вас <b>10 USD</b>";
echo htmlspecialchars($my);
```

**Версия 2** - если Вам нужно вставить в переменную теги `<b></b>`.

Используйте [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) или [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) и регулярное выражение( например, если число не известно и не известно есть ли пробел):

```
$my = "С вас 10 USD";
$my2 = str_replace('10 USD', '<b>10 USD</b>', $my);
$my3 = preg_replace("/(\d+\s?USD)/", '<b>${1}</b>', $my);

echo $my2; //С вас <b>10 USD</b>
echo $my3; //С вас <b>10 USD</b>
```

Comment: Внимательнее читайте вопрос, требуется совсем обратное.

Comment: @Manitikyl на выходе в html будет именно то, что нужно автору, т.к. сущности преобразуются в теги html. насколько можно понять именно это и нужно. Если у Вас иное предположение о том, что нужно автору поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: @Alex тут регулярка нужна.

Comment: @Эдуард хм, я подумал про html, обновил ответ

Comment: Поэтому я и сказал, внимательнее читайте вопросы. Вопрос был вполне ясен.